# Can rich text (.rtf) data be stored (and as a result searched) in a Progress CLOB

Tags: clob, progress-4gl, openedge

I know I can store .rtf file content in a BLOB, but I want to store it in a CLOB so that I can use string functions for search-and-replace.  Is it possible to store .rtf data in a CLOB?  Also, I had run into codepage issues when trying to use COPY-LOB from a .rtf file to a LONGCHAR.  Not sure what codepage conversion to use as I have not tried to convert codepages before.

Comment: Did you have any research?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle rtf-text in a CLOB as long as you know what kind of codepage was used to save the file.

Here's a short example where a RTF-file saved from Wordpad is copied to a local variable.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cRtf    AS LONGCHAR    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cString AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

COPY-LOB FROM FILE "c:\temp\rtf.rtf" TO cRTF CONVERT SOURCE CODEPAGE "utf-8".

cString = SUBSTRING(cRTF,1,100).

MESSAGE cString VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

COPY-LOB FROM  cRTF TO FILE "c:\temp\copy.rtf" CONVERT TARGET CODEPAGE "utf-8".
```

You can use REPLACE and such methods to interact with the text but you must understand that it will contain the entire RTF-string with metadata as well as the actual text

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the code sample!  I suspected you might need to know the codepage used when the RTF was created.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just brought me to a new problem.  Once I have the rich text in a longchar, and I use the "REPLACE" function to substitute text, I have no way of doing anything with the content of the LONGCHAR variable.  Attempts to save to a new .rtf file, for example, just result in: "Could not convert LONGCHAR to cpinternal. (11669)

The LONGCHAR contains characters which are not in the cpinternal codepage, or the converted string is too large."  FYI, the string is extremely short.

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried that led to the 11669 error.  I used utf-8 as the codepage, which worked fine reading the .rtf file to the longchar.  After substituting the plain text portion with another plain text (not affecting any meta characters), the COPY-LOB back to a new .rtf fails with the 11669.

Comment: Without the file it's hard do know what's wrong. Does it work without the replace?

Comment: Yes the replace succeeds.  I even tried making sure that the length of the replacement character string = length of the replaced characters (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

I work daily with RTF documents to build Word compatible documents. As I can see you're trying to do a codepage convert to load and to write the file. Everytime I need to use a RTF file I use the NO-CONVERT parameter on COPY-LOB or INPUT FROM functions because generally Windows codepage and OE internal codepages are different and if I didn't use the NO-CONVERT argument malformed documents - or weird errors such as ones that you said - are produced. Try to use COPY-LOB with NO-CONVERT parameter to write RTF files from file to CLOB fields on your database or LONGCHAR variables, do replacements as you need and then do the COPY-LOB with NO-CONVERT parameter again to RTF file.

If I understood your need you have a template that needs to be used to make documents by replacement of text inside RTF structure. If I'm right, below a piece of code that I use to do exactly the same thing. Hope it helps.

```
INPUT STREAM str-in FROM VALUE(SEARCH((IF NOT g-espelho THEN 'danfemod2.rtf' ELSE 'espelho.rtf'))) NO-CONVERT.
OUTPUT STREAM str-out TO VALUE(SESSION:TEMP-DIRECTORY + 'NF_' + STRING(tt-danfe.nrnota) + '.doc') NO-CONVERT.

REPEAT:                         

    IMPORT STREAM str-in UNFORMAT c-imp.
    IF  INDEX(c-imp,"#") > 0 THEN DO:
        ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp, "#BCCODE1281", tt-danfe.bccode1281).
        ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp, "#razaosocialempresa", tt-danfe.razaosocialempresa).
        ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp, "#sn", tt-danfe.sn).
        ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp, "#enderecoemp", tt-danfe.enderecoemp).
        ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp, "#bairroemp", tt-danfe.bairroemp).

        IF INDEX(c-imp,"#cLinha") > 0 THEN 
            ASSIGN c-aux = SUBSTR(c-imp,INDEX(c-imp,"#cLinha") + 7,2).

        IF  c-aux <> "" OR INDEX(c-imp,"#cLinha") > 0 THEN DO:
            FOR FIRST tt-linha
                WHERE tt-linha.linha = INT(c-aux):
                ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp,"#cLinha" + TRIM(c-aux),tt-linha.dados).
            END.
            IF  NOT AVAIL tt-linha THEN
                ASSIGN c-imp = REPLACE(c-imp,"#cLinha" + TRIM(c-aux),"").
        END.
    END.

    PUT STREAM str-out UNFORMATTED c-imp SKIP.

END.

PUT STREAM str-out "~\par }}".
OUTPUT STREAM str-out CLOSE.
INPUT STREAM str-in CLOSE.
```